# Highlight and copy a Numbers without the separators

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am currently making a react component where I am working with numbers.
There is an input tag for numbers, it formats the number while typing.

If I enter 50000.50 it will automatically format it to 50,000.50

Now I want to highlight this number using mouse and copy it. After pasting it to some other place it should paste it in non-formatted way like: 50000.50 (copying the actual number without the separators)

I have seen somewhere that when you select the numbers it does not highlight the separators. I want something like that. But struggling to find it.

Please help me!!!

Comment: You can remove the formatting on the event `onselect` (fires when user selects the text) and re-add it on `onblur` (fires when user deselects)

Answer (score 4):

Make use of CSS [user-select](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-user-select).

> The user-select CSS property controls whether the user can select text.

```html
<div>50<span style="user-select: none">,</span>000.50</div>
```

Comment: That's super cool :)
But what if, there is a input box that formats the number while typing and we want to select the number from that.
I think I will edit my question.

Comment: @Ragu Then you have to change the 'value' of the input on 'focus' and change it back to the formatted value on 'blur'. There is no other way afaik. Cheers

Comment: that's super ugly :) but I like it

Answer (score 0):

Stack overflow has disabled the ability to copy here, but this should work.  If you're getting your input from some source, you can set one value to copy and display it in a different format.

```js
function commafy(number) {
    return number.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
const MyComponent = () => {
  // Assume this data is coming from props or an API call
  const data = {name: 'Test', price: '50000'}
  const [copySuccess, setCopySuccess] = React.useState('');
  
  const copyToClipBoard = copyMe => {
    try {
      navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyMe);
      setCopySuccess('Price copied');
    } catch (e) {
      setCopySuccess('Failed to copy');
    }
  };

  return (
   <div>
     <div>Name: {data.name}</div>
     <div>Price: {commafy(parseFloat(data.price).toFixed(2))}</div>
     <button onClick={() => copyToClipBoard(data.price)}>
       Copy
     </button>
     <div>{copySuccess}</div>
   </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```